# Test application.properties loading during executing Spring Boot App, instead of main/application.prop

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mariadb

I've connected MARIA DB (Mysql) through spring boot application
(given mariadb details in src/main/resources/aplication.properties)

I wrote some basic test.
In test/resources/application.properties --> given H2 Database details.

If I am runing test, it is properly taking test/resources/application.properties and connecting to H2 Db and executing the tests in H2 only.

But when I am running my spring boot application, then also it is taking H2 details.(instead of MariaDB)

and if I am removing test/resources/application.properties and then  running my spring boot application-> it is taking normal MariaDB details.

Primarily it is taking test/application.properties

I want to run my application connecting MariaDB and I want to run my test cases in H2. Please help!

Project Structure as follows :
[image: Project Structure]

My main/resources/application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://MYIP/DBNAME
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8014
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
```

My test/resources/application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
logging.level.com.example.demo=DEBUG
server.port=8090
```

If I am runing main application it is runing on 8090 port only and taking h2 database details ( as configured on test/app.prop).
I want when main application is runing it should take main/resources/app.prop

My pom.xml :

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Tried adding :
'''
<build>
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
'''
then also bot working.

Comment: @pvpkiran Can you look into this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in gradle project you must include h2 as test implementation, also put a screenshot of your project structure and application.properties so we can help you

```
testImplementation "com.h2database:h2:$h2Version"
```

Comment: Hi, I am runing on maven build. Attached the screeshot of the project structure

Comment: Then add the scope to your dependency

````
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
````

Comment: I have already added the dependency--> my h2 is runing.
my question is : everything is runing on H2 (test and main application ). I want to run test on H2 database and main application on MySQL.